# Is Disney+'s Moon Knight considered to be Canon to the MCU or other Disney Marvel productions?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, continuity, moon-knight

Has the status of *Moon Knight*'s canon to the prime MCU universe (The one in which end game is depicted) been discussed in any official material, including interviews, behind-the-scenes documentaries, convention panel events\AMA, or official promotional material?

Can we, therefore, confirm or refute its canonical status and its implications, for example, were the characters affected by the Snap from the Avenger's movies, and does this mean that there is canonically an afterlife for characters in the MCU movies?

Comment: Given the efforts Disney is going towards building the MCU, it would greatly surprise me if it wasn't considered canon - even if there are no events or references to events crossing over between it and other properties.

Comment: Wikipedia is generally a good place to start looking for an answer to this type of question. [The Moon Knight page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_Knight_(TV_series)) mentions its inclusion in the MCU and includes 3 references for that.

Comment: What is canon in a multiverse?  :-D  There's at least two spider-men that don't have The Avengers in their universe.

Comment: @ mcalex, Maybe I should have said the Prime MCU universe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per official wording yes it's canon to MCU

> “Moon Knight is very much in the MCU,” executive producer Grant Curtis
> tells Inverse. “The observant viewer is going to hear and see those
> Easter eggs we drop that do explain that and confirm that.”
>
> According to Curtis, the lack of overt connective tissue between the
> series and other MCU projects simply follows what the source material
> inspires. More often than not, the source kept Moon Knight away from
> the superheroic heart of the Marvel comic book universe.
>
> “We looked at the very first comics he appeared in, in 1975, and we
> looked over the years of storytelling, over the decades of Moon Knight
> stories, [and asked] what are the themes and tones that we’re
> gravitating towards as storytellers?” Curtis says. “We never
> intentionally tried to make this standalone.” - [Inverse](https://www.inverse.com/entertainment/moon-knight-mcu-connections-interview)

And the afterlife existed already in MCU and was mentioned in Black Panther, which is indirectly connected to  Moon Knight:

> The name-drop occurred when Steven and Marc boarded Taweret's boat
> after being shot by Arthur Harrow, going across the sands of the Duat
> to see if they could gain passage into the celestial Field of Reeds.
> As they spoke about being dead with the hippo-goddess, Taweret, she
> confirmed this was no illusion -- **these realms exist for folks who die, but they're seen in different ways in various cultures.**
>
> She then spoke of the gateway from Black Panther, name-dropping the
> Ancestral Plane. Taweret was clearly in awe of it, calling it
> "gorgeous," which fans did witness in the first film. There, King
> T'Challa took the Heart-Shaped Herb, allowing him to transcend to the
> ethereal field where he spoke to his dead father, T'Chaka. - [CBR](https://www.cbr.com/moon-knight-black-panther-ancestral-plane/)

So the afterlife exists in marvel and it will be visualized based on that person's culture.

Comment: "based on that person's culture" Do you have a source for that? While having the Egyptian afterlife fit with the narrative of the show. Though i feel that was for the narrative rather based on their culture. Given that Mark an American.

Comment: @DickieBoy He's American, but he's also the avatar of an actual Egyptian god. I'd say that's a pretty good reason for him to see the Egyptian afterlife.

Comment: "So the afterlife exists in marvel and it will be visualized based on that person's culture" — possibly. Hippo goddess Taweret specifically says there are several ["intersectional planes of untethered consciousness"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/MoonKnight2022S1E5Asylum), including the Field of Reeds and the Wakandan Ancestral Plane. That doesn't guarantee that everyone gets to experience one when they die.

Comment: And it might be worth noting that, [as far as we can tell from Monica and Yelena's experiences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blip#Television_series), people who got snapped don't have any recollection of an afterlife during their 5 years away.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite nice points.

Comment: Also, Mark/Steven alone don't seem to have any cultural reasons to enter an Egyptian afterlife, but their connection to Konshu might "override" whatever other afterlife they might have gone to.

Comment: Steven studied Egyptian mythology a lot maybe that has worked.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: it's what I do 

Comment: @DickieBoy The asylum he was it was also part of his afterlife - maybe that's the American part?  Or just a sign of him going generally nuts.  It seems the afterlife is more than just cultural, it's personalized.  For example, compare T'Challa's experience with Killmonger's.  They both get that tree in the African savannah, but their other experiences differ, Killmonger getting that scene from back in America as part of his version.

Comment: Wasn't the water that they fell into after death dedicated to Taweret? Thus the setting was determined by funery rights, not personal perception?

Comment: Another reference was a bus ad for the GRC. FWIW, some people also looked more closely at the dates of Marc Spector's passport, and it seems he was likely active during the time between the Snap and the Blip.

Comment: @ Paul D. Waite, wasn't that simply because they were reconstructed, not resurrected. They don't have any memories after the snap because they were put back together exactly how they were at the time of the snap. Like restoring a computer form a backup, rather than repairing the old one.